# software on two accounts

Tags: downloads, accounts

On `Ubuntu` I have two accounts one for me and one for my sister. I downloaded a game off the `Ubuntu Software Center` but I can only play it when logged in to my account 
(The one I download it on) 
but now my sister wants to play it on her account. Is there a way to have it on two accounts with out downloading it again as I have a limited dowload amount.
I have had a look around and seen that it could not be down but that was on an older system.

Comment: did u try just to create a link of that game and place it into your sister's account?

Comment: we need more information to answer.

Comment: Hmm games from USC are they not installed system wide for all users. **confused**. What game? I do not believe you can even install a game 2 times from USC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this to do with permissions? Maybe Right Click and go on the permissions tab?

Comment: This solves the problem